# Error in textbook: $\epsilon_{ijk} u_j v_k \mathbf{e}_i = \mathbf{v} \times \mathbf{u} \neq \mathbf{u} \times \mathbf{v}$?

Tags: tensor-products, tensors

I agree with the solution until the marked spot. Then the book wants to substitute $\epsilon_{ijk}$= $-\epsilon_{kji}$ to get to $\epsilon_{kji} v_k u_j \mathbf{e}_i$, which it says is $\mathbf{v} \times \mathbf{u}$.

This of course is correct, but hasn't the book forgotten about the minus sign, and the correct result should be $-\mathbf{v} \times \mathbf{u} = \mathbf{u} \times \mathbf{v}$? Or am I the one who is missing something?

$(1.43)_2$ says $\mathbf{u} \times \mathbf{v} = \epsilon_{ijk} u_i v_j \mathbf{e}_k$, $(1.26)$ says $\mathbf{u} \times \mathbf{v} = -(\mathbf{v} \times \mathbf{u})$.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you include $(1.43)_2$ and $(1.26)$?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Edited. Just standard definitions as far as I can tell.

Comment: Hmm, I think I agree with you. Alternatively, you can use $\varepsilon_{ijk} = \varepsilon_{jki}$ to see that the expression should be $\mathbf{u} \times \mathbf{v}$.

Comment: I also agree with you. The Levi-civita symbol equals $+1$ for the case $i=1$, $j=2$, $k=3$. So the first component of the LHS equals $u_2 v_3-u_3v_2$, which is the same as what you get using the cross product of $u$ and $v$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been established in the comments, you are correct, there is a missing negative. We have

$$\mathcal{E} : (\mathbf{u}\otimes\mathbf{v}) = \varepsilon_{ijk}u_jv_k\mathbf{e}_i = -\varepsilon_{kji}v_ku_j\mathbf{e}_i = -\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{u} = \mathbf{u}\times\mathbf{v}.$$

Alternatively,

$$\mathcal{E} : (\mathbf{u}\otimes\mathbf{v}) = \varepsilon_{ijk}u_jv_k\mathbf{e}_i = \varepsilon_{jki}u_jv_k\mathbf{e}_i = \mathbf{u}\times\mathbf{v}.$$